# Mdframed for theorems: how to make fonts similar to amsthm and change title format?

Tags: fonts, theorems, mdframed

I am making a custom book style for my thesis, and I came up with a style for the theorem environments that I like, as you can see in the image below. However I have two problems:

1. I would like the theorem's title to be in parenthesis, as is the case with the usual amsthm's theorem
2. I would like the theorem environments to be similar to amsthm's environments. For example, the theorem's body would be in italics, and the remark's title would be in not boldface italics.

I know that these issues can be solved by using the package thmtools, however I could not find a way to reproduce this style and colors, in particular I could not make the title to appear in this shaded bar, and
I also had issues with shaded theorems not braking along pages, wich is a must for me, as I am going to have some long ones.

Could somebody tell me how I can produce the same result, but with my two issues solved?

**Extra question:** I learnt from experience that when I'm having a hard time changing latex styles, there is a good reason for that, and changes produce worse results. I guess it's a matter of taste, but from a typesetting point of view, is there a good reason to avoid doing the changes I'm asking here?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{lipsum} %dummy text
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,table]{xcolor} 
\definecolor{lightblue}{rgb}{.31,.506,.741}
\definecolor{pale}{HTML}{F7F8E0}

\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}
\usepackage{tikz}

\theoremstyle{theorem}
\mdfdefinestyle{mytheoremstyle}{%
linewidth =0pt, %
frametitlerule =true, %
frametitlebackgroundcolor=lightblue!20,
backgroundcolor=pale,
} 

\theoremstyle{theorem}
\mdfdefinestyle{mytheoremstyle}{%
linewidth =0pt, %
frametitlerule =true, %
frametitlebackgroundcolor=lightblue!20,
backgroundcolor=pale,
} 

\mdtheorem[style=mytheoremstyle]{theorem}{Theorem}[section]

\theoremstyle{remark}
\mdfdefinestyle{myremarkstyle}{%
linewidth =0pt, %
frametitlerule =true, %
frametitlebackgroundcolor=lightblue!20,
backgroundcolor=pale,
} 

\mdtheorem[style=myremarkstyle]{remark}[theorem]{Remark}

\begin{document}
\section{A section}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{theorem}[The theorem's title]
    I would like two things:
    \begin{enumerate}
    \item the theorem's title to appear in parentheses, 
          like ``Theorem 1.1. (The theorem's title.)''
    \item the fonts to be in italics, like the
    amsthm's theorem style
    \end{enumerate}
\end{theorem}
\lipsum[2]

\begin{remark}
I would like the fonts to be as in amsthm's remark
style.
\end{remark}

\end{document}
```

Comment: commenting only on your last question -- " is there a good reason to avoid doing the changes I'm asking here?"  admittedly biased answer, no, i can think of no good reason.  in fact, the typographic distinctions in `amthm` were made on the basis of long tradition, so to *not* recognize them would be breaking with tradition.  unrelated comment: some people have had good results with `tcolorbox`; haven't used it myself, so this is second hand only.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, good to know.  I'll take a look at tcolorbox

Comment: @barbarabeeton tcolorbox did the job! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tcolorbox did the job with the following:

```
\usepackage[theorems]{tcolorbox}

\tcbset{
theostyle/.style={
    fonttitle=\bfseries\upshape,
    fontupper=\slshape,
    before skip=\baselineskip,
    arc=0mm, 
    boxrule=0mm, 
    left=0mm,
    right=0mm,
    coltitle=black,
    colback=pale,
    colframe=lightblue!30,
    breakable,
    description delimiters parenthesis,
    separator sign none,
    terminator sign={.}
}}

\newtcbtheorem[number within=section]{theorem}{Theorem}{theostyle}{theorem}
```